# Non-Binary Tree Data Structure in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, tree, trie

[image: example]

Does anyone have an idea as to how I could recreate this:

**The end objective is to traverse the tree and count every endpoint. In this case `3` because 1, 3, 2 are all endpoints.**

Comment: Edit the question to show what you have tried.

Comment: It depends on your purpose and use case.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use simple lists, you could build a basic class. Something like:

```
class NonBinTree:

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.nodes = []

    def add_node(self, val):
        self.nodes.append(NonBinTree(val))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"NonBinTree({self.val}): {self.nodes}"


a = NonBinTree(0)
a.add_node(1)
a.add_node(3)
a.add_node(4)
a.nodes[2].add_node(2)

print(a)
```

And then add whatever other methods you want.

Comment: I particularly appreciate the __repr__ method example. Thanks!

Comment: @chuck If I have the same set up, but instead had the nodes structured as variables & coefficients, how would I be able to define the nodes via their baseline children components? As I ask in this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73903349/how-to-list-node-composition-from-non-binary-tree-in-terms-of-pre-defined-base-l